# Hauppauge WinTV does not work on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, video-capture-card

I cannot get my WinTV card to work with Ubuntu 12.04.
The same card has worked in previous versions of Ubuntu, and I know the card is working because the PC has dual booting and it works fine in Windows.
The card is recognised and shows up as BT878 Hauppauge /dev/video0 in applications, but I get garbage when try to use it.
Are you able to help out?

Comment: I tried lspci and the card is detected as: Brookstree Corporation Bt878 Video Capture (rev 11) and Brookstree Corporation Bt878 Audio Capture (rev 11)

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake, I was not selecting the correct video input for the card, so I was getting the video from an input which didn't have any signal.
After the selecting the correct input (composite video in my case) I was able to capture the video.